# OutOfMemoryError while using javax.json.JsonReader

Tags: android, json

I thought by using JsonReader instead of StringBuilder, it would have solved my Out Of Memory error, but it doesn't seem so.

Logcat points that the error was coming from this line:

```
resultFromWeb = hf.retrieveGuestData(hf.urlWebService, postParameters);
```

So here's my retrieveGuestData

```
public JsonObject retrieveGuestData(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs){
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        JsonObject finalResult = null;

        HttpEntity entity;
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(inputStream);
            finalResult = reader.readObject();

            return finalResult;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return finalResult;
    }
```

And here's my logcat message:

```
 E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 168-byte allocation.
 I/dalvikvm: "AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=14 RUNNABLE
 I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x2bc34380 self=0x450a80
 I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=23441 nice=10 sched=3/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=4605968
 I/dalvikvm:   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1059 stm=27 core=0
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Throwable.nativeFillInStackTrace(Native Method)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:160)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:83)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:37)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:35)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:33)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.HashMap.makeTable(HashMap.java:-1)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.HashMap.doubleCapacity(HashMap.java:575)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:405)
 I/dalvikvm:     at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl.putValueMap(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:153)
 I/dalvikvm:     at org.glassfish.json.JsonObjectBuilderImpl.add(JsonObjectBuilderImpl.java:75)
 I/dalvikvm:     at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:191)
 I/dalvikvm:     at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readArray(JsonReaderImpl.java:143)
 I/dalvikvm:     at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:180)
 I/dalvikvm:     at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:103)
 I/dalvikvm:     at com.evenesis.imin.evenesis.HelperFunctions.retrieveGuestData(HelperFunctions.java:121)
 I/dalvikvm:     at com.evenesis.imin.evenesis.EventList$RetrieveGuestData.doInBackground(EventList.java:296)
 I/dalvikvm:     at com.evenesis.imin.evenesis.EventList$RetrieveGuestData.doInBackground(EventList.java:265)
 I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
 I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
 I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 W/dalvikvm: Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;)
 W/dalvikvm: Could not resolve class ref'ed in exception catch list (class index 2496, exception Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;)
 I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 49.925MB to 48.000MB
 D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 1% free 48990K/49159K, paused 3ms+6ms
 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41450K, 85% free 7540K/49159K, paused 364ms
 W/dalvikvm: threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using JsonReader won't solve your problem. You need to look for the close and ending tag to read object out of it and consume it. But it would be better if you write the response to file and then read it in chunk from there.

Hope it gives you some idea to start with.